# Change the delimiter in Apache Superset while extracting csv

Tags: apache-superset

I need to change a delimiter from ',' to ";" for more convinient further data processing after extracting table to csv. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in config.py. Change field `CSV_EXPORT` like `CSV_EXPORT = {"encoding": "utf-8", "sep": ";"}`. Also you can change charset for windows cyrillic users for example `CSV_EXPORT = {"encoding": "cp1251", "sep": ";"}`